# Find a good way to get a coverage report on ES6 code

Tags: jasmine, babeljs, systemjs, istanbul, karma-coverage

Here is my problem : in an AngularJS project, I use Babel 6 (ES2015 + stage3 + decorators), SystemJS and Karma + Jasmine.

All is OK, except for code coverage : I can't find a good way to get a coverage report on ES6 code instead of transpiled ES5.

I have some restrictions :

- no Github npm dependencies
- no deprecated projects (like isparta)
- should run on Windows (yeah, I know, but I have to) and GNU/Linux

This question is especially oriented to a local html coverage report, but I also need a format that could be used in SonarQube.

There seems to be a huge lake of support on this question (especially with Decorators and SystemJS), so, along with some issues on Github, maybe the stackoverflow community could share a way to do this.

If you need some extras, you can see this project on Github ([Sedona-Solutions/sdn-angularjs-seed](https://github.com/Sedona-Solutions/sdn-angularjs-seed)), and look at the related issues ([Sedona-Solutions/sdn-angularjs-seed#5](https://github.com/Sedona-Solutions/sdn-angularjs-seed/issues/5)) with references to all related issues and projects I could found.

**About remap-istanbul**

Here is my transpilation and mapping gulp task :

```
gulp.task('es6', function () {
  return gulp.src(paths.source, { base: 'app' })
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(changed(paths.output, { extension: '.js' }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(babel(compilerOptions))
    .pipe(ngAnnotate({
      sourceMap: true,
      gulpWarnings: false
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.output))
});
```

Karma-coverage

```
coverageReporter: {
            reporters: [
                {
                    type: 'json',
                    dir: 'target/coverage/',
                    subdir: '.',
                    file: 'coverage-final.json'
                }
            ]
        }
```

and the test:remap gulp task :

```
gulp.task('test:remap', ['test'], function (done) {
    return gulp.src(paths.coverage + '/coverage-final.json')
        .pipe(remapIstanbul({
            reports: {
                'json': paths.coverage + '/coverage.json',
                'html': paths.coverage + '/html-remaped/'
            },
            fail: true,
            useAbsolutePaths: true
        }));
});
```

due to [the first remap-istanbul issue](https://github.com/SitePen/remap-istanbul/issues/1), I get the following error :

```
C:\...\sdn-angularjs-seed\node_modules\remap-istanbul\node_modules\istanbul\lib\report\html.js:288
                    text = structuredText[startLine].text;
                                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
  at C:\...\sdn-angularjs-seed\node_modules\remap-istanbul\node_modules\istanbul\lib\report\html.js:288:53
```

You can see the corresponding code [on github](https://github.com/Sedona-Solutions/sdn-angularjs-seed/tree/remap-coverage).

It could be an error on some mapping generation, or paths ... If you think so, tell me.

Answer (score -1):

karma-coverage + remap-istanbul should work fine

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Remap-istanbul was indead my first idea, but if you look at the github issue referenced in the question, the issue [SitePen/remap-istanbul/#1](https://github.com/SitePen/remap-istanbul/issues/1) prevent to generate the html report.

I tried the following script :
`remap-istanbul -i target/coverage/coverage-final.json -o target/coverage/remap/remap.json -b ./ && istanbul report --root target/coverage/remap --dir target/coverage/remap/rslt html`
but there isn't any file at the end (there seems to be a lot of problems with Windows paths, among other things).

Comment: I've been successfully using remap-istanbul since last september. It  generates html reports, lcov and Cobertura reports. You're doing something wrong probably. I use grunt. Here is my configuration:

    var remapIstanbulConfig = {
      build: {
        src: '.coverage/coverage.json',
        options: {
          reports: {
            json: '.coverage/coverage.json',
            lcovonly: '.coverage/lcov.info',
            html: '.coverage/html'
          },
          useAbsolutePaths: true
        }
      }
    };

Comment: I added some infos in the question for you. If you want more details, you could see my project. Trust me, I tried a lot of possibilities with remap-istanbul, and I get this error every time ... but it could be due to a bad map or karma-coverage report ... or a lake of Windows paths support ... I'll continue to investigate, but if you have some ideas, I would be glad to follow.

Comment: I set up a basic example with the same settings I use in my projects
https://github.com/alexeibs/ts-example

It's working on Windows

Comment: It's a Typescript project but I guess it doesn't matter

Comment: There is a lot of differences between your project and mine : gulp/grunt, ts/es6, decorators ... Following your advise, I created a new test:remap task in a new [remap-coverage](https://github.com/Sedona-Solutions/sdn-angularjs-seed/tree/remap-coverage) branch in my project ... but the error on html generation is still here. I think there is something wrong with the mapping, but I can't find what for now (and it's working perfectly for all the rest). I'll test this version on a GNU/Linux to see if the issue could be related to windows paths.

Comment: Yes, there are differences but these differences are minor. gulp/grunt - they only run tasks. ts/es6 - these are only different ways of transpiling code. Decorators are runtime objects, they should not affect code transpiling and coverage reports. I've been successfully using decorators in TS code.

Comment: The TS/ES difference isn't that minor, given that the issue could be related to mapping generation.
About the decorators, babel6 support it thanks to a decorators-legacy plugin. And a lot of coverage report or mapping solutions doesn't support that. For example, if we add the identityMap parameter to gulp-sourcemaps, an error occur due to an "wrong" @ character.
Anyway, thanks for the help. This discussion begin to become really to long for a stackoverflow answer comment :) I'll continue to look at remap-istanbul#1, and if you want to help, you are welcome to contribute to sdn-angular-seed.

Comment: Yes, I also have issues for the code coverage with the combination systemjs/es6 and istanbul... Cannot make it work.. @noelmace, were you able to sort this out?